# Getting Problem to Display arabic text in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

when i am trying to display arabic text in asp.net mvc view. it shows Ø²Ø¹ØªØ± Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø¬Ø¨Ù†Ù‡ cheracters how to fixed it ?[image]

Comment: Is it unicode?.

Comment: i don't know unicode sir. in database it is nvarchar.

Comment: Nvarchar means it is Unicode (which is good).

Comment: then why i am getting this Ø²Ø¹ØªØ± Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø¬Ø¨Ù†Ù‡  in view

Comment: Is one of the HTTP headers `content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, where UTF means it is Unicode encoded, so the browser knows how to handle the textual content?

Comment: try to add in your html `<head>` tag => `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: like `<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></head>`

Comment: Additionally to setting utf-8 encoding for the view, make sure to add `dir="rtl"` to your respective `td` or `div` containers with Arabic text in your view/partial

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: now dear. still getting These Characters Ø²Ø¹ØªØ± Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø¬Ø¨Ù†Ù‡

Comment: after adding above commented code did u try to hard refresh your view by hiting `Ctrl + F5` two to three times. If not then try this

Comment: How are you getting your text from the database? It does come from a database, right?

Comment: try to add this in your `head` => `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: also try to add `dir="ltr" lang="ar"` these attribute to parent element of your `table` or each of `td` in your table

Comment: check the text in the db, is it saved correctly? And do you have any charset settings in your connection string?

Comment: sir it is not working. i tried all the above techniques still getting error

Comment: the text id db is correct . actually i am getting data from database through web api . whenever i get data through web api then it return correct data but when i am trying to get data through controller then it returns incorrect data.

Comment: I just did some quick checks: this is obviously proper Arabic in UTF-8 encoding, only not resolved. I assume your html head is determined by a global shared Layout.cshtml? Do a simple "View source" in your browser on your rendered page. Is the charset meta tag there?